# Is this virus threat fake or is Waterfox infected?

Tags: firefox, virus, anti-virus

Avast keeps popping up this notification:

[image: antivirus alert]

I did a full system scan and it didn't find anything. What should I do? Get a different antivirus? When I click on "more details" it takes me to [this Avast website](http://www.avast.com/en-ca/lp-pr-virus-alert?p_ext=&utm_campaign=Virus_alert&utm_source=prg_ise_70_1&utm_medium=prg_systray&utm_content=./paid/en-ca/virus-alert-default&p_vir=URL:Mal&p_prc=C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CWaterfox%5Cnspr4.dll&p_obj=http://toolbarservice.freecause.com/2.6/?action=rewards_xul&toolid=100493&userid=107987594&username=f87f8d00c5a828009595d2d14c4c1c848da2a33e&time=1351110398&hash=6d169586e9e7dd9692b97e06f725a2d1&username=f87f8d00c5a828009595d2d14c4c1c848da2a33e&session_key=noPassword&session_id=1&p_var=./paid/en-ca/virus-alert-default&p_pro=2&p_vep=7&p_ves=0&p_lqa=0&p_lsu=24&p_lst=1&p_lex=3&p_lng=en&p_lid=en-ca&p_elm=7&p_vbd=1466).

Comment: It shows that a virus tried to infect your browser, but Avast blocked it. Sometimes when trusted sites are infected and you get attacked from those sites, you go to another infected site and you get an alert like that. However, the alert box changed in newer versions. The alert box shown is from an older version of Avast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently that particular url in the "object:" line is passing out malware, no infection on your pc but could be infected if you go to that url (website).

Websites become infected and pass out malware to your pc when you visit them, and most of the time the owner/operator of the website has no clue they have been hacked to serve malware.

If they clean the website of the malware more than likely Avast will stop alerting on that particular URL.

If you do not use waterfox, uninstall it.

Comment: It pops up all the time, even on this website!

Comment: @Celeritas: check or disable all waterfox add-ons you may have installed. One of them may be loading ads behind the scenes. Also remove any 3rd party toolbars

Comment: @Celeritas it has nothing to do with Websites you are visiting, something is loading in the background that Avast does not like. Uninstall Waterfox Software if you do not use it or know what it is.

Comment: @Moab: Waterfox is a legitimate web browser. The issue is not down to the (vanilla) program.